# identify all the dependencies inside a list with a ranking imposed on it

Tags: sorting, ranking

Suppose you have a list of triplets characterized by a dependency relation among them defined as follows:
the last element of the triplet specifies the "rank" n of the triplet inside the hierarchy, the second element identifies the other triplet that "dominates" the one in question, with a higher rank of n-1. In this way you can
produce a path for every triplet of the list, having, for instance, the following form:

50,152,3 -> 152,49,2 -> 49,3,1 -> 3, NULL, 0

692,1642,1 -> 1642,NULL,0

The objective is, given a list where such a dependency hierarchy holds, output all the possible paths obtainable
given the starting triples.

Is there a way to do this with the least amount of full reading of the whole list?

One idea would be to read the list once, creating a dictionary for every rank, and then scanning again the list and reporting the path checking in the respective dictionary of higher level the associated triplet.

But this is expensive in terms of data structure used for the ranks:

A different way would be assuming an ordering in the list, such that for instance the triplet 50,152,3 is followed by the triplet at index 152, 152,49,2, and that this last triplet is followed by triplet at index 49.
This should allow getting the result with just one data structure that includes the whole list and for each element checking the element related to the index identified by the second place of the tuple. If the order is not present, we would need to force it into the list, creating our keys for that.

Are there other, more efficient solution for the problem in question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this by reading the list and maintaining a map from indices to the associated path. For example, for the list

```
<code>[50, 152, 3]
[49, 3, 1]
[3, null, 0]
[692, 1642, 1]
[1642, null, 0]
</code>
```

your map would be

```
<code>{
  0: [50, 152, 3, 49, 3, 1, 3, null, 0],
  1: [3, null, 0],
  3: [50, 152, 3, 49, 3, 1, 3, null, 0],
  692: [692, 1642, 1, 1642, null, 0],
  1642: [692, 1642, 1, 1642, null, 0]
}
</code>
```